# Mocking joblib cache using pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, joblib

I want to test a function that uses `joblib`'s caching functionality.

I am wondering how to skip the cache and call the actual function when performing a unit test using pytest? Is it suitable to mock something like `joblib.Memory`?

Let's say I have the following function:

```
from joblib import Memory

memory = Memory(location="cache")

@memory.cache
def func(a):
    return a**2

def test_func():
   assert func(2) == 4
```

How am I supposed to mock the caching functionality and force `func` to be executed everytime I call it from within the test function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions cached by `joblib.Memory` have a `.func` attribute that provides access to the underlying function.  See the documentation [here](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/memory.html#joblib.memory.MemorizedFunc).  So you could write your test as follows:

```
from joblib import Memory

memory = Memory(location="cache")

@memory.cache
def func(a):
    return a**2

def test_func():
   assert func.func(2) == 4
```